# How do I re-queue a test that has been postponed on Drupal.org?

Tags: testing

I'm trying to run the tests on a patch on Drupal.org.  The relevant issue is [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2457813#comment-9784579).  The status is marked as **Test request sent** but more than a week has passed and the test hasn't been run.

I tried changing the issue status from *Needs review* to *Needs work* and then back to *Needs review* but that didn't re-queue the test.  If the test has been run, whether it succeeded or failed, there is usually a **Re-test** link, but since the test is marked as "test request sent" then the link does not appear.

How can I re-queue such a test?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can post an issue to the [drupal.org testbots project issue queue](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/testbot) and get someone to look into it.